# What's the difference in meaning between "talking about this" vs. "to talk about this"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference, infinitive-vs-gerund

I think

> *It makes me feel nervous **talking** about this.*

means talking about that topic is making the speaker feel nervous while

> *It makes me feel nervous **to talk** about this.*

means if they were to talk about that topic, it would cause the speaker to feel nervous.

I think that's the difference between the two sentences. Do you agree with me?

Comment: The distinction you perceive is hair thin and likely to be invisible to most people.

Comment: There's not much in it at all. I wouldn't notice any difference.

Comment: I agree with what everyone else says about the (non-)difference in meaning. However, in this particular sentence, I think "talking about this" sounds more natural than "to talk about this". I'd probably word it as: _I feel nervous talking about this._

Comment: It certainly sounds more natural if you start with that clause. Talking about this makes me nervous.

Answer (score 2):

In the Current sentences the difference is almost non-existent. There can be cases in which the sentences may have different applied meanings if you change a lot of the words. However, within conversational English there is no difference.